# Recurring event every N'th hour/day/week/month

Tags: recurring-events

Is it possible to have recurring tasks in Sharepoint<sup>*</sup> that collect certain data from lists and sends them in an email?

I want to send an email with records `X` that match criteria `Y` from list `Z` every `N'th` hour/day/week/month.

Even though I'm a programmer, I would prefer to use Sharepoint designer, since I'm not so thrilled by the thought of learning the tools, environment and the 10K other things you're forced to when approaching a new environment and/or language.

<sub>*recurring as in; do "`A` if `B`" or "do `A` every date `B`"</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I believe sharepoint designer cannot address your need. Having said that it is important to choose the right and clean solutions. I think you cannot avoid writing code and writing a custom timer job could be the right choice for you. There are plenty of resources and examples available out there if you google it.

Answer (score 0):

Tasks lists don't have recurrance built into them, the only ones who do are calendar lists.  The most applicable thing I can think OOTB of is using a workflow to handle the emails on specific occurances or using some sort of IRM or alert process.